# Play Framework CRUD pagination

Tags: pagination, playframework, crud

How do I set the page size in the Play Framework CRUD module? Whats the default page size? 
Currently I have over 20 records in the table and no paging navigation has appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the following in the configuration file:

```
set crud.pageSize={my page size}
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean there is a propery you can set in application.conf. Unfortunately I don't found it at the moment. Have a look to the code of CRUD-module